# Cron to check call the URL if not running

Tags: cron, centos

I have to run a cron job that will call the URL every 1 hour and for that I am doing this
* */1 * * * wget http://example.com?count=1000

But sometimes it takes more than an hour to complete the job. I want to check if the cron job is already running, it should not run the job.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: taking an hour seems not right - is this really the case?

Comment: Yes, it process 1000s of emails and this is known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a script file such as the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ps aux | grep "wget http://example.com?count=1000" | grep -v "grep" 2>&1 >/dev/null
exit_code=$?
if [ "$exit_code" -ne 0 ]
then
  wget http://example.com?count=1000/
fi
```

This script basically checks if the `wget ...` command is already running. If it is, it exits, otherwise it runs it.

And then call this script in your cron:

```
* */1 * * * /path/to/script
```

By the way, if you want to run the script every hour, the following crontab entry would also work:

```
0 * * * * /path/to/script
```

Comment: will this be a shell script?

Comment: Yes, it will be a shell (bash) script.

Comment: doing `nano tasker.sh` and put the above code into the file and run that .sh file in the cron. Is this what you are suggesting?

Comment: What permissions would I have to give to this script?

Comment: Executable: `chmod u+x /path/to/script`

Comment: Also, if you want to run the script every hour, you might wanna do `0 * * * *`.

Comment: It is downloading the temporary files. ``Resolving www.posclean2.bid... 217.61.21.172 Connecting to www.domain.com|127.0.0.30|:80... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 772 [text/html] Saving to: “script.php?count=5000%2F.1” 100%[=======================================================‌​====================‌​====================‌​====================‌​====================‌​>] 772 --.-K/s in 0s 2018-02-24 21:13:32 (91.4 MB/s) - “script.php?count=5000%2F.1” saved [772/772]``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165761/discussion-between-baig772-and-pgngp).

Answer (score 0):

Run it as script doing some kind of locking:

```
if mkdir /var/lock/.wget.lock
then
  wget http://example.com?count=1000
  rmdir /var/lock/.wget.lock
fi
```

There is also [flock](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) which is doing quite the same as above - just better.